# Why does ptrace show a 32-bit execve system call having EAX = 59, the 64-bit call number? How do 32-bit system calls work on x86-64?

Tags: linux, x86-64, system-calls, 32bit-64bit, ptrace

I'm toying `ptrace` with the code below. I found that the system call number for `execve` was 59 even when I compiled with the `-m32` option. Since I'm using Ubuntu on a 64-bit machine, it could be understandable.

Soon, the question arose: "Do libc32 behave differently on 32-bit machine and 64-bit machine? Are they different?" So I checked what libc32 had in 64-bit. However, the `execve` system call number for libc was 11, which was identical the `execv` system call number for 32-bit systems. So where does the magic happen? Thank you in advance.

Here's the code. It's originated from https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6100

```c
#include <sys/ptrace.h>                                                                                                           
#include <sys/types.h>                                                                                                            
#include <sys/wait.h>                                                                                                             
#include <unistd.h>                                                                                                               
#include <sys/user.h>                                                                                                             
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                  
int main()                                                                                                                        
{                                                                                                                                 
        pid_t child;                                                                                                              
        long  orig_eax;                                                                                                           
        child = fork();                                                                                                           
        if (child == 0) {                                                                                                         
                ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);                                                                            
                execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);                                                                                     
        } else {                                                                                                                  
                wait(NULL);                                                                                                       
                orig_eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,                                                                                
#ifdef __x86_64__                                                                                                                 
                                child, &((struct user_regs_struct *)0)->orig_rax,                                                 
#else                                                                                                                             
                                child, &((struct user_regs_struct *)0)->orig_eax,                                                 
#endif                                                                                                                            
                                NULL);                                                                                            
                printf("The child made a "                                                                                       
                        "system call %ld\n", orig_eax);                                                                           
                ptrace (PTRACE_CONT, child, NULL, NULL);                                                                          
        }                                                                                                                         
        return 0;                                                                                                                 
}
```

Here's result from the code

```
~/my-sandbox/ptrace$ file s1 && ./s1
s1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=f84894c2f5373051682858937bf54a66f21cbeb4, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
The child made a system call 59

~/my-sandbox/ptrace$ file s2 && ./s2
s2: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=cac6a2bbeee164e27c11764c1b68f4ddd06405cf, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
The child made a system call 59
```

This is what I got from 32bit executable using gdb. As you can see it's using /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6, and the system call number for execve is 11.

```
>>> bt
#0  0xf7e875a0 in execve () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0xf7e8799f in execl () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x565562a4 in main () at simple1.c:15
>>> disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function execve:
=> 0xf7e875a0 <+0>: endbr32 
   0xf7e875a4 <+4>: push   %ebx
   0xf7e875a5 <+5>: mov    0x10(%esp),%edx
   0xf7e875a9 <+9>: mov    0xc(%esp),%ecx
   0xf7e875ad <+13>:    mov    0x8(%esp),%ebx
   0xf7e875b1 <+17>:    mov    $0xb,%eax
   0xf7e875b6 <+22>:    call   *%gs:0x10
   0xf7e875bd <+29>:    pop    %ebx
   0xf7e875be <+30>:    cmp    $0xfffff001,%eax
   0xf7e875c3 <+35>:    jae    0xf7dd9000
   0xf7e875c9 <+41>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: libc used the VDSO wrapper exported by the kernel, so it can benefit from `sysenter` on machines that support it, instead of slower `int $0x80`.  See https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/ for an overview of that.

Comment: (my prev. comment was based on just the title).  As you can see, the 32-bit libc execve wrapper is passing EAX=11 with `mov  $0xb,%eax`.  IDK why your program is finding that EAX=59 in that case.  I would definitely also expect 11 there, `__NR_execve` from `unistd_32.h`, especially since we can see the libc wrapper passing that.  Unlike Windows WOW64, 32-bit user-space on Linux calls into the kernel directly, not far-jumping to 64-bit mode for `syscall`.  So yes, 32-bit user-space libraries aren't special on a 64-bit system; a 64-bit kernel simply provides a 32-bit ABI for 32-bit processes.

Comment: Yes. I checked that libc32 on 32-bit machin is not different from libc32 on 64-bit machin. My question is altough libc hand 11 (on 64-bit machine with 32-bit elf) for execve why kernel (which is 64-bit) treat it as 59 and how.

Comment: Yes, I could see that kernel could/should only reserve 59 for exeve. then where 11, execve on 32-bit elf, transform to 59 ?

Comment: Perhaps inside the kernel, as an implementation detail of the 32-bit syscall wrapper, on the way to executing the execve code that checks for `PTRACE_TRACEME` actually raises SIGTRAP on execve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execve` is special; it's the only one that has special interaction with `PTRACE_TRACEME`.  The way `strace` works, other system calls *do* show the 32-bit call number.  (And modern strace [needs special help](https://superuser.com/questions/834122/how-to-distinguish-syscall-from-int-80h-when-using-ptrace) to know whether that's a 32-bit call number for `int 0x80` / `sysenter`, or a 64-bit call number, since 64-bit processes can still invoke `int 0x80`, although [they normally shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code).  This support [was only added in 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53456266/can-ptrace-tell-if-an-x86-system-call-used-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-abi), with `PTRACE_GET_SYSCALL_INFO`)

---

You're right, when the kernel is actually invoked, EAX holds `11`, `__NR_execve` from `unistd_32.h`.  It's set by `mov    $0xb,%eax` before glibc's execve wrapper jumps to the VDSO page to enter the kernel via whatever efficient method is supported on this hardware (normally `sysenter`.)

But execution doesn't actually stop until it reaches some code in the main `execve` implementation that checks for `PTRACE_TRACEME` and raises `SIGTRAP`.

Apparently sometime before that happens, it calls `void set_personality_64bit(void)` [in arch/x86/kernel/process_64.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/process_64.c#L664), which includes

```
    /* Pretend that this comes from a 64bit execve */
    task_pt_regs(current)->orig_ax = __NR_execve;
```

I found that by [searching for `__NR_execve`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/__NR_execve) in a kernel source browser, and looking at the most likely file in arch/x86.  I didn't keep cross-referencing to find where that's called from; the fact that it exists (and the assumption of a sane non-obfuscated design) points very strongly to this being the answer to your mystery.

Comment: @dyjin: you can "accept" an answer with the checkmark under the vote arrows, if it fully answers your question.

Comment: Yes, thank you. sorry for that. I'm newbie here.